# Matching numerical pattern

Tags: java, regex

I'm doing a project which requires numerical pattern matching.
For example i want to know whether `Value = 1331` is a part of   `680+651 = 1331` or not, i.e. i want to match `1331` with `680+651 = 1331` or any other given string.
I'm trying pattern matching in java for the first time and i could not succeed. Below is my code snippet.

```
String REGEX1=s1;   //s1 is '1331' 
pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX1);
matcher = pattern.matcher(line_out);   //line_out is for ex. 680+651 = 1331
System.out.println("lookingAt(): "+matcher.lookingAt());
System.out.println("matches(): "+matcher.matches());
```

It is returning false all the times.
Pls help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `matches` method requires a perfect, full exact match. Since there is more text in `680+651=1331` than what is matched by the regex `1331`, matches returns `false`.

As I pointed out in Brian's post, you need to be careful in your regex to ensure that a regex of `1331` does not match the number `213312` unless that is what you want.

Comment: (?:^|[^\\d])1331(?:[^\\d]|$) is fine. But if the matching string is somewhat like `1331-2662= -1331` it is returning true. how to avoid this.

Comment: `(?:^|[^\\d\\-])1331(?:[^\\d]|$)`

Answer (score 3):

`matches()` requires that the pattern be a complete match, not a partial.

You either need to change your pattern to something like `.*= 1331$` or use the `find()` method which will do a partial match.

Comment: To find `1331` anywhere, try `(?:^|[^\\d])1331(?:[^\\d]|$)`

Comment: I don't know that you really need the lookahead/behind stuff with this simple problem, but sure :) Didn't want to confuse the poor guy.

Answer (score 2):

`matches()` is the wrong method for this, use `find()`.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html says:

> public boolean matches()
>
> Attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern.

and

> public boolean find()
>
> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.